# Is it legal to POST/PUT/PATCH list and leaf-list in RESTCONF?

Tags: rest, ietf-netmod-yang, ietf-restconf

This is a follow-up question of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56124918/is-it-legal-to-get-all-list-instances-in-restconf) post. From @predi's answer I know that it is legal to `GET` a URL whose target resource is a list or leaf-list and `DELETE` can't use such URL. That is to say, given the following YANG definitions:

```
list machine {
    key "name";
        leaf "name" {
        type string;
    }
}
```

The request `GET /restconf/data/test/machine` is legal. The request `DELETE /restconf/data/test/machine` is illegal.

I want to confirm if other methods like `POST`, `PUT` or `PATCH` can use list or leaf-list as URL target resource in requests. For example, are below requests legal in RESTCONF?

```
POST   /restconf/data/test/machine
PUT    /restconf/data/test/machine
PATCH  /restconf/data/test/machine
```

Currently I think the `POST` and `PUT` requests are illegal and not sure about the `PATCH` request.

Here are my reasons:

From [3.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8040#section-3.5):

> Containers, leafs, leaf-list entries, list entries, anydata nodes, and
> anyxml nodes are **data resources**.

So a leaf-list or list is not a data resource. Only a leaf-list entry or list entry is a data resource.

From [4.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8040#section-4.4):

> The POST method is sent by the client to create **a data resource** or
> invoke an operation resource. The server uses the target resource type to
> determine how to process the request.
>
> ```
>   +-----------+------------------------------------------------+
>   | Type      | Description                                    |
>   +-----------+------------------------------------------------+
>   | Datastore | Create a top-level configuration data resource |
>   | Data      | Create a configuration data child resource     |
>   | Operation | Invoke an RPC operation                        |
>   +-----------+------------------------------------------------+
>
>                  Resource Types That Support POST
> ```

So the listed target resource type is `DATA`, a data resource.

From [4.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8040#section-4.5):

> The PUT method is sent by the client to create or replace the **target
> data resource**.

I haven't found similar descriptions in the PATCH section. The PATCH section just talks about `target resource`, not `target data resource` or `data resource`.

But ther are also ambiguous words in PUT and PATCH sections:

> If the target resource represents a YANG leaf-list, then the PUT
> method MUST NOT change the value of the leaf-list instance.
>
> If the target resource represents a YANG leaf-list, then the PATCH
> method MUST NOT change the value of the leaf-list instance.

It seems that the target resource can represent a leaf-list, but later it says "MUST NOT change the value of the **leaf-list instance**". If using a leaf-list as the target resouce, a PUT or PATCH must not change which leaf-list instance?

Given this:

```
leaf-list names {
    type string;
}
```

and the JSON encoded instances:

```
names: ["a", "b", "c"]
```

There are three leaf-list instances: a, b and c. If using:

```
PUT .../names
```

then you can only create or replace the whole leaf-list, how can you `MUST NOT change the value of the leaf-list instance`?

Thanks,

Comment: To get an answer for this one, it would be best to direct the question to [NETCONF/RESTCONF mailing list](https://www.ietf.org/mailman/listinfo/netconf). The authors of the document always respond if clarification is needed.